# Random point inside annulus with a shifted hole

Tags: python, math, random, geometry, point

First of all, will appreciate if someone will give me a proper term for "annulus with a shifted hole", see exactly what kind of shape I mean on a picture below.

Back to main question: I want to pick a random point in the orange area, uniform distribution is not required. For a case of a usual annulus I would've picked random point in (r:R) range and a random angle, then transform those to x,y and it's done. But for this unusual shape... is there even a "simple" formula for that, or should I approach it by doing some kind of polygonal approximation of a shape?

I'm interested in a general approach but will appreciate an example in python, javascript or any coding language of your choice.

[image: shifted annulus]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple method that gives a uniform distribution with no resampling.

For simplicity assume that the center of the outer boundary circle (radius `r_outer`) is at `(0, 0)` and that the center of the inner circular boundary (radius `r_inner`) lies at `(x_inner, y_inner)`.

Write `D` for the outer disk, `H1` for the subset of the plane given by the off-center inner hole, and `H2` for the *central* disk of radius `r_inner`, centered at `(0, 0)`.

Now suppose that we ignore the fact that the inner circle is not central, and instead of sampling from `D-H1` we sample from `D-H2` (which is easy to do uniformly). Then we've made two mistakes:

- there's a region `A = H1 - H2` that we might sample from, even though those samples shouldn't be in the result.
- there's a region `B = H2 - H1` that we never sample from, even though we should

But here's the thing: the regions `A` and `B` are congruent: given *any* point `(x, y)` in the plane, `(x, y)` is in `H2` if and only if `(x_inner - x, y_inner - y)` is in `H1`, and it follows that `(x, y)` is in `A` if and only if `(x_inner - x, y_inner - y)` is in `B`! The map `(x, y) -> (x_inner - x, y_inner - y)` represents a rotation by 180 degress around the point `(0.5*x_inner, 0.5*y_inner)`. So there's a simple trick: generate from `D - H2`, and if we end up with something in `H1 - H2`, rotate to get the corresponding point of `H2 - H1` instead.

Here's the code. Note the use of the square root of a uniform distribution to choose the radius: this is a standard trick. See [this article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html), for example.

```
import math
import random

def sample(r_outer, r_inner, x_inner, y_inner):
    """
    Sample uniformly from (x, y) satisfiying:

       x**2 + y**2 <= r_outer**2

       (x-x_inner)**2 + (y-y_inner)**2 > r_inner**2

    Assumes that the inner circle lies inside the outer circle;
    i.e., that hypot(x_inner, y_inner) <= r_outer - r_inner.
    """
    # Sample from a normal annulus with radii r_inner and r_outer.
    rad = math.sqrt(random.uniform(r_inner**2, r_outer**2))
    angle = random.uniform(-math.pi, math.pi)
    x, y = rad*math.cos(angle),rad*math.sin(angle)

    # If we're inside the forbidden hole, reflect.
    if math.hypot(x - x_inner, y - y_inner) < r_inner:
        x, y = x_inner - x, y_inner - y

    return x, y
```

And an example plot, generated by the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
samples = [sample(5, 2, 1.0, 2.0) for _ in range(10000)]
xs, ys = zip(*samples)

plt.scatter(xs, ys, s=0.1)
plt.axis("equal")
plt.show()
```

[image: uniform samples from annulus with off-center hole]

Comment: Could you explain the reflection part a bit more? Would it would if the origin is in the forbidden region? Also, is sampling from the squares of the radii what is causing the distribution to be uniform rather than polar? If so, this observation may "fix" some of the other answers that have a polar distribution.

Comment: 2nd question first: Yes, taking the square root of a uniform distribution gives the right distribution for a radius; that's a standard trick. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html

Comment: And yes, the reflection works if the origin is contained in the inner hole. The key fact is that for _any_ point (x, y) in the plane, `(x, y)` is in `H1` if and only if `(x_inner - x, y_inner - y)` is in `H2`. Everything else follows from there.

Comment: Well, that's the most elegant approach in my opinion. I didn't even thought about looking at the problem from this perspective. 
Needless to say - works as a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JaredGoguen: And strictly speaking, what I'm doing is a rotation by π rather than a reflection. I've edited the question.

Comment: agreed with Max, by far the most elegant solution and even produces a uniform distribution

Comment: @JaredGoguen Acceptance/rejection method would produce uniform distribution as well - if you start with uniform one

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I personally don't like it because it's not guaranteed to terminate and that makes me uneasy. Just feel clumsy when there is an efficient method

Comment: @JaredGoguen while Mark presented clever way to sample (kudos to him, +1), I believe it really only works if radial distribution is uniform. Suppose I want to sample with radial distribution PDF being parabolic, like a bowl. Or other way around, gaussian or polynomial (like Cauchy) bell-like shape. I don't believe Mark's transformation preserve the R distribution shape. And I even won't talk about the case where both R and angular distributions are non-uniform and even somehow mixed/correlated.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need exact sampling? Because with acceptance/rejection it should work just fine. I assume big orange circle is located at (0,0)

```
import math
import random

def sample_2_circles(xr, yr, r, R):
    """
    R - big radius
    r, xr, yr - small radius and its position
    """
    x = xr
    y = yr
    cnd = True
    while cnd:
        # sample uniformly in whole orange circle
        phi = 2.0 * math.pi * random.random()
        rad = R * math.sqrt(random.random())
        x = rad * math.cos(phi)
        y = rad * math.sin(phi)

        # check condition - if True we continue in the loop with sampling
        cnd = ( (x-xr)**2 + (y-yr)**2 < r*r )

    return (x,y)
```

Comment: I can't say that i "need" it, but would def prefer it, since in edge case when inner circle is close in size to outer - this loop will potentially run for a whole bunch of iterations (slow, will hang everything) until it finaly stumbles at acceptable point.

Comment: @MaxYari that's correct, efficiency will go down as soon as inner circle is growing. From the other hand, any kind of uniform/non-uniform sampling denepdendcy is very easy to implement and prove.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have shown no equation, algorithm, or code of your own, but just an outline of an algorithm for center-aligned circles, I'll also just give the outline of an algorithm here for the more general case.

The smaller circle is the image of the larger circle under a similarity transformation. I.e. there is a fixed point in the larger circle and a ratio (which is R/r, greater than one) such that you can take any point on the smaller circle, examine the vector from the fixed point to that point, and multiply that vector by the ratio, then the end of that vector when it starts from the fixed point is a point on the larger circle. This transformation is one-to-one.

So you can choose a random point on the smaller circle (choose the angle at random between 0 and two-pi) and choose a ratio at random between 1 and the proportionality ratio R/r between the circles. Then use that the similarity transformation with the same fixed point but using the random ratio to get the image point of the just-chosen point on the smaller circle. This is a random point in your desired region.

This method is fairly simple. In fact, the hardest mathematical part is finding the fixed point of the similarity transformation. But this is pretty easy, given the centers and radii of the two circles. Hint: the transformation takes the center of the smaller circle to the center of the larger circle.

Ask if you need more detail. My algorithm does not yield a uniform distribution: the points will be more tightly packed where the circles are closest together and less tightly packed where the circles are farthest apart.

---

Here is some untested Python 3.6.2 code that does the above. I'll test it and show a graphic for it when I can.

```
import math
import random

def rand_pt_between_circles(x_inner, 
                            y_inner,
                            r_inner, 
                            x_outer,
                            y_outer,
                            r_outer):
    """Return a random floating-point 2D point located between the 
    inner and the outer circles given by their center coordinates and 
    radii. No error checking is done on the parameters."""
    # Find the fixed point of the similarity transformation from the
    #   inner circle to the outer circle.
    x_fixed = x_inner - (x_outer - x_inner) / (r_outer - r_inner) * r_inner 
    y_fixed = y_inner - (y_outer - y_inner) / (r_outer - r_inner) * r_inner 

    # Find a a random transformation ratio between 1 and r_outer / r_inner
    #   and a random point on the inner circle
    ratio = 1 + (r_outer - r_inner) * random.random()
    theta = 2 * math.pi * random.random()
    x_start = x_inner + r_inner * math.cos(theta)
    y_start = y_inner + r_inner * math.sin(theta)

    # Apply the similarity transformation to the random point.
    x_result = x_fixed + (x_start - x_fixed) * ratio
    y_result = y_fixed + (y_start - y_fixed) * ratio

    return x_result, y_result
```

Comment: I'm really confused to be honest. What exactly is proportionality ratio? R/r? And what the use of this random number between 1 and ratio. Guess I had to think this over tomorrow with a clear head. Will appreciate any additional tips for dummies though.

Comment: @MaxYari: I improved my explanation of the overall proportionality ratio R/r just before you did your comment, so I cannot take credit for that quick reply. I did improve my explanation of the random ratio after your comment. Is it clear now?

Comment: Can you walk through that with me?  
For ex R = 6, r = 2;   
`1.` I pick a random angle (a) and a point (l) along r: a = Pi, l = 1;    
`2.` Next is a random ratio: rt = 2;    
`3.` ???

Comment: @MaxYari: See the added code to my answer. I'm too busy right now to test the code or include a graphic.

Comment: Ran it with following params: `x_inner` = 10, `y_inner` = 10, `r_inner` = 10, `x_outer` = 0, `y_outer` = 0, `r_outer` = 50;
And getting `x_result` and `y_result` in a range exceeding 50 (even 200+)

Comment: Seems that ratio should be `1+((r_outer/r_inner-1) * random.random());`

Comment: It indeed works (still trying to figure out HOW it works to be honest :D ), but I really liked Mark's approach in the end and decided to accept his answer. Thanks a lot for you input!

Answer (score 1):

The acceptance/rejection method as described by Severin Pappadeux is probably the simplest.

For a direct approach, you can also work in polar coordinates, with the center of the hole as the pole.

The polar equation `(Θ, σ)` (sorry, no rho) of the external circle will be

```
(σ cosΘ - xc)² + (σ sinΘ - yc)² = σ² - 2(cosΘ xc + sinΘ yc)σ + xc² + yc² = R²
```

This is a quadratic equation in `σ`, that you can easily solve in terms of `Θ`. Then you can draw an angle in `0, 2π` an draw a radius between `r` and `σ`.

This won't give you a uniform distribution, because the range of `σ` is a function of `Θ` and because of the polar bias. This might be fixed by computing a suitable transfer function, but this is a little technical and probably not tractable analytically.